# How to pass jwt to prisma middleware in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I am using nestjs, graphql, & prisma. I am trying to figure out how to pass my jwt token for each database request to the prisma service iv created. Iv tried an object to the constructor but then wont compile saying I am missing a dependency injection for whatever I reference in the constructor paramter.

```
@Injectable()
export class PrismaService
  extends PrismaClient
  implements  OnModuleDestroy {
  constructor() {
    super();
    //TODO how do I pass my jwt token to this for each request?
    this.$use(async (params, next) => {
      if (params.action === 'create') {
        params.args.data['createdBy'] = 'jwt username goes here';
      }
      if (params.action === 'update') {
        params.args.data['updatedBy'] = 'jwt username goes here';
      }

      const result = await next(params);
      return result;
    });
  }

  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.$disconnect();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are getting your JWT token from the request, you can use **NestJS CLS** library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-cls

> The main idea of Async Local Storage is that we can wrap some function call with the AsyncLocalStorage#run call. All code that is invoked within the wrapped call gets access to the same store, which will be unique to each call chain.

https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/async-local-storage

Here's how I passed my decoded JWT token to each Prisma database query.

```ts
//app.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClsModule.forRoot({
      middleware: {
        mount: true,
        setup: (cls, req) => {
          cls.set('jwt', req.headers['jwt']);
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [...],
  controllers: [...],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Also, you can set values to CLS Store via the interceptor

```ts
//jwt.interceptor.ts
@Injectable()
export class JWTInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(private readonly cls: ClsService) {}

    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const jwt = // logic to extract jwt token from request
        this.cls.set('jwt', jwt);
        return next.handle();
    }
}
```

Then you can access the stored value inside a prisma middleware like this

```ts
//prisma.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(private readonly cls: ClsService) {
    super();
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();

    this.$use(async (params, next) => {
      const jwt = this.cls.get("jwt");
      return next(params)
    });
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a nest middleware?

JWT is normally passed to a Controller, not a service.

Example:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
 private backend: any // This is your backend

 constructor() {
   this.backend = null // initialize your backend 
 }

 use(req: Request, res: Response, next: any) {
   const token = <string>req.headers.authorization


   if (token != null && token != '') {
     this.backend
       .auth()
       .verifyIdToken(<string>token.replace('Bearer ', ''))
       .then(async (decodedToken) => {
         const user = {
           email: decodedToken.email,
           uid: decodedToken.uid,
           tenantId: decodedToken.tenantId,
         }
         req['user'] = user
         next()
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         log.info('Token validation failed', error)
         this.accessDenied(req.url, res)
       })
   } else {
     log.info('No valid token provided', token)
     return this.accessDenied(req.url, res)
   }
 }

 private accessDenied(url: string, res: Response) {
   res.status(403).json({
     statusCode: 403,
     timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
     path: url,
     message: 'Access Denied',
   })
 }
}
```

So every time I get an API call with a valid token, the token is added to the `user[]` in the request.

In my Controller Class I can then go ahead and use the data:

```js
@Post()
  postHello(@Req() request: Request): string {
    return 'Hello ' + request['user']?.tenantId + '!'
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I just learned about an update in Nest.js which allows you to easily inject the header also in a Service. Maybe that is exactly what you need.

So in your service.ts:

```js
import { Global, INestApplication, Inject, Injectable, OnModuleInit, Scope } from '@nestjs/common'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core'

@Global()
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: any) {
    super()
    console.log('request:', request?.user)
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    // Multi Tenancy Middleware
    this.$use(async (params, next) => {
      // Check incoming query type
      console.log('params:', params)
      console.log('request:', this.request)
      return next(params)
    })

    await this.$connect()
  }

  async enableShutdownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
    this.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
      await app.close()
    })
  }
}
```

As you can see in the log output, you have access to the entire request object.

Comment: Opening and closing an entire database connection pool(!) for every HTTP request is not recommended. This will slow down the entire application. Also, your shutdown hook will stop the entire application by calling `app.close()`. See https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/connection-management#calling-disconnect-explicitly

Comment: Additionally, you only call `$connect()` on the `PrismaClient` (for each request). This will result in an out of memory exception. There will be a new connection pool for each request - but the connection pool won't be closed after the request is done.